# How to send email in django with attaching dynamic context passed invite.ics file?

Tags: django, email, celery, invite

My is a simple celery asyncronus task which sends email attaching invite.ics file, but i dont know how to pass dynamic context in invite.ics file?

my task file for sending email ->

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
from django.core.mail import send_mail 
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


@shared_task
def send_email_with_celery(company, date, sender, receiver):
    email = EmailMessage(f'Interview with {company}', f'You have been selected for the interview at time {date}', f"{sender} from {company}", [f'{receiver}'])
    email.attach_file('invite.ics', 'text/calendar')
    email.send()
    return None
```

my invite.ics file-->

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:{{ sender }} <-- dynamic sender context
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Sonu Sud:MAILTO:{{ receiver }} <-- dynamic reciever context
DTSTART:20201005T110000Z <-- should be dynamic time value in this format
DTEND:20201005T114500Z <-- should be dynamic time value in this format
SUMMARY:Interview with {{ company }} <-- should be dynamic Company name    
GEO:48.85299;2.36885 
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

i want to pass the context like this ->

```
context = {
        "sender":,
        "receiver":,
        "start":,
        "end":,
        "company":
    }
```

how to pass the context in invite.ics file...?